# Ignore undefined facts in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm running queries against a generated set of facts, and some facts may not exist. When that happens, SWI Prolog errors out with e.g. `Undefined procedure: 'LongIdent'/4`. Is there a way to get it to instead simply have the goal involving `'LongIdent'/4` fail?

Comment: What if you just write another predicate to check it and if exists call the predicate else fail e.g: `check(LongIdent(....) ). -> false if LongIdent/4 does not exist else call LongIdent/4` would this be ok??

Comment: If these are dynamic facts, you should use the directive, `:- dynamic('LongIdent'/4).`. This tells Prolog that it's a real predicate or fact but may not have been asserted (yet).

Comment: @coder Not unless I was able to apply that globally / to a whole file?

Comment: @lurker The issue there is that the set of facts may change; for each data file it's constant, but there might be different facts generated. It'd be a bit of a pain to enumerate them, too...

Comment: @NathanRingo, let's say you define a predicate check as I described, the only thing you need to do is firstly load the predicate check definition and you will call your predicate snot directly like: predicate1(...) but check(predicate1(...)) if that's ok then this could work for a file of predicates...

Comment: @coder The issue is that I'm using the generated predicates (the ones that may or may not exist) in a lot of places; doing the `check(...)` every time I use one would be a lot of code changes.

Comment: @NathanRingo if that's the case, then most certainly it's dynamic. But you do need to alert Prolog of any dynamic predicates/facts. If you can't then you need to resort perhaps to what coder suggested. Look up other predicates that SWI has to offer that are reflective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could change the default behavior using [unknown/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=unknown/2) which is declared as `unknown(-Old, +New)`, `Old` is the old-current flag, `New` is the new flag that you use:

```
?- unknown(trace,fail).
Warning: Using a non-error value for unknown in the global module
Warning: causes most of the development environment to stop working.
Warning: Please use :- dynamic or limit usage of unknown to a module.
Warning: See http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/database.html
true.

?- a(1).
false.
```

But you see the warnings explaining that this may not be a good idea...

If you don't know the current/old flag you could use it like:

```
?- unknown(X,fail).
    Warning: Using a non-error value for unknown in the global module
    Warning: causes most of the development environment to stop working.
    Warning: Please use :- dynamic or limit usage of unknown to a module.
    Warning: See http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/database.html
    X = trace.
```